# Unable to unset xbindkeys map for mouse buttons

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I tried using xbindkeys and xte to create a copy/paste mapping for my Logitech Mx Master mouse and in the process I was testing using different mouse buttons.

This is my current config

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:9

"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:8
```

But the problem is my middle mouse button now, pastes, and left mouse button copies. I don't want this and I think this is a byproduct of my testing.

I tried resetting the xbindkeys config, uninstalling, reinstalling but to no avail.

Does it change some system file somewhere and isn't unsetting it?

Answer (score 0):

You could verify that those buttons map correctly with `xev | grep button` and then clicking those mouse buttons to make sure they are 8 and 9. I just did this and [this was the article](https://www.thecrumb.com/2015/06/03/xbindkeys/index.html) I referenced.

Comment: When I do that and click left mouse button it `state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES` which is good and expected (right?) but the button still copies.

Comment: The copy part is weird. I know the middle mouse button thing is a setting possibly in your Mouse Settings. It's a toggle that you can shut off the action for your middle mouse button. As for the left mouse button, that is still a mystery. Button 1 is correct, but it almost sounds like something else somewhere on your system is assigning that value for the left button click. Like you tried this before or, there's a leftover config somewhere.

Comment: I guess just to rule it out, you could get another mouse to see if the same behavior happens on that machine, or take your current mouse and bring it to another machine and see if the behavior is in the mouse itself (which happens sometimes) or if it's a setting on your machine.

Comment: So I tried that with the touchpad and the issue was still happening xD I ended up giving up and reinstalled the OS.